# Can I use Twilio conversations API for realtime chat feature

Tags: flutter, twilio, chat, twilio-conversations

I'm developing a flutter app with a feature where users can chat in real time and make audio/video calls. can I use **Twilio**'s APIs for them. It seems Twilio have no flutter packages for these APIs. Is it possible to use Twilio in my app and what are the alternatives if not.

Comment: yes you can do that... here is the documentation of twilio https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason that you cannot use Twilio in your Flutter application to do real time chat and audio/video calls. At Twilio we do not officially support Flutter as a platform, but there are community built plugins that wrap both the [Video](https://pub.dev/packages/twilio_programmable_video) and [Conversations API](https://gitlab.com/twilio-flutter/conversations) that might help you out.